# I can't connect to a staging site developed in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-studio

I made a staging for a site developed in the zend framework. All cPanel has moved to a new server. Unfortunately after making the changes on my pc in the host file I can not see the site. Do I have to change something in the database?

Comment: If you can't see the site, what do you see instead? A timeout or an error message of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload your apache server:
    sudo service apache2 reload